# can Logstash fetch data from 2 different sources in single Input JDBC section?

Tags: input, jdbc, logstash

I am working on migrating logstash pipelines to read data from snowflake instead of sql. While most of my source data is available in snowflake, Couple tables are meant to be still in sql database as per requirements. All my pipelines could use the snowflake now, except one which has a special use case.

One logstash pipeline have Input JDBC section with query which now needs to read from sql as well as snowflake.

Is there a way I can mention 2 different sources in Input JDBC section for my query to read from both ?